# How to tag UIImage in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to assign them to have tag:

```
self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg",nil];
```

Whenever UIScrollView stops at a specific image it will do something/action/animation. Like for example drawing a box at the left when image 1 is displayed, drawing a box at the right when image 2 is displayed in a UIScrollView. Thanks.

here is the array :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{    
    if (self) {

        //set up carousel data
        //wrap YES = infinite loop
        wrap = YES;

        self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg"nil];
    }

}
```

here is where my image is shown:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]]];

    return view;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "Whenever a specific image is diplayed in a UIScrollView an animation/action will be done"?

Comment: I think you know, that you don't have any images (but strings) in the code you posted...

Comment: Its declared in the awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer on basis what I got from the comments on other answers (You really should edit your question!!!).

I assume that there is a UIScrollView in paging mode which shows exactly one image on his full frame after scrolling has stopped. If you only interested in getting this image and do something, let's say dependent on a tag you set before, the code in your scroll view's delegate could look like that:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  int imageTag;
  for(UIView *sv in scrollView.subviews) 
  {
    if(sv.frame.origin.y >= scrollView.contentOffset.y 
       && sv.frame.origin.y <= scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) 
    {
      imageTag = sv.tag;
      break;
    }
  }
  switch (imageTag) 
  {
      //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: It says `No member named 'y' in struct CGSize`.

Comment: I want to be able to achieve that for example if image1 is where the UIScrollview stops it will draw a box, when image 2 is where the UIScrollview stops it will draw a box to the right. And I have 75 images.

Comment: @bry Hmm... my code does not access any `y` in a `CGSize`. Did you copy&paste

Comment: @bry should be fine for 75 images or more (maybe there is a more efficient way, but I don't think it's necessary).

Comment: YES,should I declare a value in scrollView.contentOffset.y?

Comment: edited my answer: the method in delegate should be `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Comment: okay, but I've already synthesize,declare the contentOffset but still having the same error.

Comment: and I'm pretty sure that you changed my code a bit, so that it contains something like `scrollView.frame.size.y` now.

Comment: there's nothing to declare or synthesize for you. Everything I used is part of the UIKit. I strongly recommend to read the [docs on how to use `UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html):

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about on navigation next image to be displayed. then check sample code here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

and if any thing else. then explain what

Comment: Whenever UIScrollView stops at a specific image it will do something/action/animation. Like for example drawing a box at the left when image 1 is displayed, drawing a box at the right when image 2 is displayed in a UIScrollView. Thanks.

Comment: i thnk this can be accessed by checking which page is selected.

Comment: I'm using a Vertical UIScrollView

Comment: develope a method that will check the current selected page. as your pages are static and you know what image is on what page, and then draw the drawing as you want using AVFoundation etc

Comment: yeah bt i'm talking about page controller which can also be vertical

Comment: So your `UIScrollView` is `paging=YES` and each page contains exactly one image?

Comment: It's like a slot machine, a vertical carousel.

Comment: So you have actually a UIScrollView which has multiple UIImageViews?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the x-coordinate of the images ? That seems to be a legit way to check what picture is showing... If you want tag, you can either use the indexes, or store the pointers to the images in a dictionary.

Comment: Can you show the code of how you are adding the images to the scrollview? Then I can put a sample up.

Comment: Here: - (void)awakeFromNib2
{    
    if (self) {
        
        //set up carousel data
        //wrap YES = infinite loop
        wrap = YES;
        
        self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg",nil];
    }
}

Comment: Do you mind editing your post so the code is easier to read. And also, I was looking for how you were adding your Images to the Scrollview, this is just putting the files in the array. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have some pictures in a vertical scrollview, and whenever the scroller positioned at one of these images, a new image should be drawn?

Comment: kindly check my edited post. When a uiscrollview stops at a specific place it draws a box in the right like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply calculate the offset of your UIScrollView, by using the following formula:

```
NSUInteger currentPage = floor((yourScrollView.contentOffset.y - theHeightOfYourImage/2) / theHeightOfYourImage)+1
```

This is from the top of my head, but if I'm not wrong this will give you the current page that's at the moment selected. Of course this needs all your pages/images to have the same height.

You could implement this in

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

This would then give you an index to work with.